# ASP.NET MVC How to combine two variables to use in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, variables, filter

in my ASP.NET MVC web app I have two variable, one is used for filtering, the other is used for displaying a table which only displays Sites appointed to a User. How do I return both of these to a list? I'm guessing I have to combine these two, but I'm am uncertain how to do that.

```
 public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchName, string searchSite, string searchShift, string searchArea, string searchDiscipline)
    {


        //Filter ViewBags
        ViewBag.FullNameFilter = (from e in db.Employees
                                  select e.FullName).Distinct();

        ViewBag.SiteFilter = (from e in db.Employees
                                  select e.Site.SiteName).Distinct();

        ViewBag.ShiftFilter = (from e in db.Employees
                              select e.Shift.Shift1).Distinct();

        ViewBag.AreaFilter = (from e in db.Employees
                              select e.Area.Area1).Distinct();

        ViewBag.DisciplineFilter = (from e in db.Employees
                              select e.Discipline.Discipline1).Distinct();


        if (Session["Name"] == null)
        {
            TempData["msg"] = "Your Session Expired - Please Login";
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }

        string name = Session["Name"].ToString();
        var EmployeeIDCatch = db.Employees.Where(s => s.Email.Equals(name)).Select(s => s.EmployeeID).FirstOrDefault();
        var des = (from c in db.SitesPerEmployees where c.EmployeeID == EmployeeIDCatch select c.SiteID);
        var employeesSearch = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Area).Include(e => e.Discipline).Include(e => e.Shift).Include(e => e.Site).Where(e => des.Contains(e.SiteID));

        var employees = from e in db.Employees
                        where e.FullName == searchName || searchName == null || searchName == ""
                        where e.Site.SiteName == searchSite || searchSite == null || searchSite == ""
                        where e.Shift.Shift1 == searchShift || searchShift == null || searchShift == ""
                        where e.Area.Area1 == searchArea || searchArea == null || searchArea == ""
                        where e.Discipline.Discipline1 == searchDiscipline || searchDiscipline == null || searchDiscipline == ""
                        select e;

        return View(employeesSearch.ToList());
```

I'd like it so that the table can be filtered and also display sites that have been assigned to certain users.

Comment: Why don't you just do filtering on employeesSearch instead of db.Employees?

Comment: @Andrei I need it to display only the sites users have been assigned. I fix the problem, see the answer below!!

Answer (score 0):

Right, so I actually just figured it out right after posting this. I'll post the answer in case anyone has any similar problems. I did just combine the two

```
  var employees = from e in db.Employees.Include(e => e.Area).Include(e => e.Discipline).Include(e => e.Shift).Include(e => e.Site).Where(e => des.Contains(e.SiteID))
                        where e.FullName == searchName || searchName == null || searchName == ""
                        where e.Site.SiteName == searchSite || searchSite == null || searchSite == ""
                        where e.Shift.Shift1 == searchShift || searchShift == null || searchShift == ""
                        where e.Area.Area1 == searchArea || searchArea == null || searchArea == ""
                        where e.Discipline.Discipline1 == searchDiscipline || searchDiscipline == null || searchDiscipline == ""
                        select e;
```